# Runtime Error for linkedlists in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am getting a runtime error whenever I run this code for implementing a linked list. I think the error is in the default constructor as I tried to run the program in which only the object was created nothing else was done.

The linkedlist.h file is

```
#ifndef LinkedList_h
#define LinkedList_h

#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    string song;
    node *next;
};

class LinkedList{
    private:
        node *head;
        int listLength;
    public:
        LinkedList();
        bool insertNode(node *newnode, int position);
        bool removenode(int position);
        void printList();
        ~LinkedList();
};

#endif
```

The linkedlist.cpp file is

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include<iostream>

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    head = new node;
    head->song ="head";
    head->next=NULL;
    listLength = 0;
}

bool LinkedList::insertNode(node *newnode, int position){
    if(position<=0 || position >listLength+1)
        {
            cout<<"Error: position is out of range";
            return false;
        }
    if(head->next == NULL){
        head->next = newnode;
        listLength++;
        return true;
    }
    int count = 0;
    node *p=head;
    node *q=head;
    while(q){
        if(position == count){
            p->next=newnode;
            newnode->next = q;
            listLength++;
            return true;
        }
    p=q;
    q=p->next;
    count++;
    }
    cout<<"Unable to insert the element due to technical issues";
    return false;
}

bool LinkedList::removenode(int position){
    if(position<=0 || position > listLength+1){
        cout<<"Invallid position\n";
        return false;
    }
    if(head->next ==NULL){
        cout<<"The list is already empty\n";
        return false;
    }
    int count =0;
    node *q = head;
    node *p = head;
    while(q){
        if(count==position){
        p->next = q->next;
        delete q;
        listLength--;
        return true;
        }
    p=q;
    q=p->next;
    count++;
    }
    cout<<"Error removing elements";
    return false;
}

void LinkedList::printList(){
    int count=0;
    node *p = head;
    node *q = head;

    if(head->next==NULL){
        cout<<"The list is empty\n";
    }
    while(count<listLength){
        cout<<"\n"<<p->song<<endl;
        q=p;
        p=q->next;
        count++;
    }
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList() 
{
    node * p = head;
    node * q = head;
    while (q)
    {
        p = q;
        q = p -> next;
        if (q) delete p;
    }
    delete head;
}
```

The main.cpp is

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include "linkedlist.cpp"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    node *A = new node;
    A->song = "Swatch";

    node *B = new node;
    B->song = "one plus 2";

    node *C = new node;
    C->song = "Woodland";

    LinkedList l;
    l.insertNode(A,1);
    l.insertNode(B,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I am getting a runtime error". Then debug it. That's what people do when they get errors. The best tool to help you with that is a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never initialize head in the constructor. This will cause a runtime error. You need to add a statement like

```
head = new node;
```

Then remember to delete it when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Now the problem is with your destructor. Notice that in the first run of your while loop you will delete the head node. Then after you finish the while loop, you delete head again. Deleting already freed memory will cause a runtime error.

Comment: Another comment now that I see the full code. You might want the constructor to initialize an empty list instead of having a useless head node. You can just set head=NULL in the constructor, and you need to check if the head is null in the insert and print methods.